# Django Migrations: Modifying Field of Model After Database in Use

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have created a Django web application that has models and many instances of models created. The problem is that I want to add another field to one of the models already in use (has over 1000 instances). I have had difficult experiences with Django Migrations in the past and am scared that if I modify the model by adding the field, my web application will not function.

How do I change the model in such a way that it will not affect the functionality of my web application?

Comment: Can you explain which model field do you want to add?

Comment: I want to add a string field.

Comment: add this field with default empty string and if this field is not unique then it's safe for you.

Comment: The field is going to be unique because it will be an alternative id for the model

Comment: You still have to a) add the field as non-unique with a default, then b) migrate, c) populate it with unique values, d) set it to unique in the model and e) migrate again. As long as the field is not used by your application, it's unlikely that its presence would break the application.

Comment: I will be using the field in my application after all the data is populated. Would that cause problems? How would I check to make sure all data is populated correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following should solve your problem without introducing any issues.

You can check that the data has been populated correctly by checking the fields in django admin if need be.

I would suggest, however, that you set yourself up with a dev environment so that you can test this kind of thing without worrying about whether it's going to cause issues on your production environment.

I hope this helps!

---

Initial:

**Models.py**

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

First change:

**Models.py**

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    unique_str = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True) # add this here
```

Run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then you can run a script to populate your unique_str:

```
# get all model instances
example_models = ExampleModel.objects.all()

# update each unique_str as required
for e in example_models:
    e.unique_str = e.pk # add any required logic here to assign value to this variable
    e.save()
```

Finally:

**Models.py**

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    unique_str = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True) # add unique
```

and then again, Run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```